# Get Data from a date range in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to get data for a specific date range, I do it like this:

```
select EntryID
       min(dtUsedDate) dtFirstUsedDate,
       max(dtUsedDate) dtLastUsedDate
from tblEntrance e
where e.dtUsedDate between to_date('2016-02-08 10:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') 
   AND to_date('2016-02-08 10:15:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

(dtFirstUsedDate and dtLastUsedDate are getting called in a outer select, so don't worry much about them for now)

What I get are the entrances (records) that are only between those dates/time, so dtFirstUsedDate and dtLastUsedDate, both toghether  in between that date range. But what I need is those two to be independent, like the dtFirstUsed must be between that max and min date and dtLastUsed must be between that max and min date.

I hope my question is understandable and someone can help me.

Comment: Wouldn't the min and max of `dtUsedDate` just be the two ends of the range in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: The above query won't work. There is no `group by EntryId`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes it does what you say, but I need to modify the query to ignore the other case if false if one is true. And since I am new in oracle I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output to clarify.

Comment: @GurV this code is shortened because I thought this is enough information and that the full code is too long, so I focused only on the date part. If you really need more code I can provide more details.

Comment: @Arianitax I am not asking for code. I am asking for sample data and expected output.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. If you select **only** the rows where `dtUsedDate` is between the values in the `where` clause, then the min and the max over `dtUsedDate` is **only for those rows**, so they will also, automatically, be between the same values. What is your concern (what are you worried about)?

Comment: @mathguy what I wanted to do is to get the records where the date of dtFirstUsedDate is in between that selected date or the dtLastUsedDate is between that selected date, like an logic or `||`, but I get the result like an and `&&`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this..

```
    SELECT e.EntryID
      ,MIN(e.dtUsedDate) dtFirstUsedDate
      ,MAX(e.dtUsedDate) dtLastUsedDate
  FROM tblEntrance e
 GROUP
    BY e.EntryID
 HAVING MIN(e.dtUsedDate) BETWEEN TO_DATE('2016-02-08 10:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') 
                              AND TO_DATE('2016-02-08 10:15:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
    AND MAX(e.dtUsedDate) BETWEEN TO_DATE('2016-02-08 10:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') 
                              AND TO_DATE('2016-02-08 10:15:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

Comment: This is a very brave attempt - guessing at "group by" when there is no hint of anything like that in the original post. In any case, if that was indeed the requirement, you would only need to check that `min(e.dtuseddate) >= ...` and `max(e.dtuseddate) <= ...` - you are doing twice as many checks as needed.